# How do I delete these vertices? They are only visible in face selector mode

Tags: modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, vertices, faces

So I'm in Blender Render, and I need to delete the extra points on the edges of themiddle left plane. I'm contructing the abdominals for a man, and everytime I try to subdivide this plane blender crash/closes. I think it has something to do with these extra points. How do I delete them? Disclaimer: this is my first blender project. 
                          P.S.- Any other tips? Criticism? I know so very little.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wyatt, welcome to the site. You might want to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and study the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help), paraticularly the bits about asking ahd answering questions.

Comment: Note that vertices are only visible in vertex select mode, and faces in face select mode. If you're in face select mode, and see what appears to be a vetex which is only visible in face select mode, it's not a vertex.

Comment: Generally Blender shouldn't crash regardless of what are you doing - removing doubles or subdividing. If it crashes *only* because of subdividing it's a bug and should be reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not vertices, they are faces with a very small area.

To delete them you either:

- Select all and remove doubles by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> then *Remove Doubles*;
- Or manually remove them and join the vertices by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You could just press <kbd>W</kbd> in Edit mode and choose *Remove doubles* to remove extra overlapping vertices.

Comment: Note that this was already proposed in another answer.

Comment: ah sorry for that, i haven't seen the other answer yet :o
thank you for the notification though